# setting FORGE_HOME path in mac

Tags: macos, jboss, jboss-forge

I set the home path in the `.profile`

```
export FORGE_HOME=/Users/sreesaran/forge-distribution-1.3.2.Final
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin:$VISAGE_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$FORGE_HOME/bin
```

This is how i saved in the .profile and forge-distribution-1.3.2. Final is where the bin resides and  whenever i type forge in terminal i get this:

```
-bash: forge: command not found
```

I also set the home path in: `/etc/launchd.conf`
Can some throw light on me and please explain about setting home path in mac

[Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Will following this thread be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the file doesnt seem to have the write premission set , that is why the changes mades in the file are not taking effect , so check whether it has write persmission , if not change save it and it will work